# Reset identity Column to 0

Tags: c#, linq

For the beginning the structure of my database and my program.

I have a simple database that contains 3 tables.

- Server
- Ressources
- Avg_ressources

Ressources and Avg_Ressources contain a foreign key from Server. Both also include a primary key.

My program writes every second the cpu usage, ram usage and the time into the Ressources table. The writing part is in a thread(reason behind this is that I get information through a stream over a network from multiple servers)

In another thread I run an class with methods to group the data from the Ressources table and insert them into the Avg_Usage table. Until now everything works as intended.

Now comes the part where the error occurs.

After I´m done inserting the data into the table I try to delete the data from the old table with

```
db.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Ressources")
```

db in this case is my DataContext. The data from Ressources gets deleted but the primary key still contains the same value. On the next insert the program fires the following error + stacktrace

```
System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException

System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.PostProcessUpdates(List`1 insertedItems, List`1 deletedItems) at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) 
    at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) 
    at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
```

I already tried `db.ExecuteCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT (Ressources, RESEED, 0)");`

but it didn´t worked out either.
Just to notice I also tried using db.Refresh before inserting data into Ressources but that didnt solved the problem. And when I´m using the command directly on the db through sql server manager it works fine.

Now my question is:

Do I have to stop my other threads to actually reset the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem and even found the reason for the error.

The DataContext didnt refresh so it still had the old primary keys and therefore throw the error with the duplicate key.

To solve the problem I added the following code:

```
   db.GetType().InvokeMember(
   "ClearCache",
   BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
   null, db, null);
```

I just call an intern method from DataContext and that has done the trick.